# Non hierarchical mind map software

Tags: mind-mapping

I have been searching for a mind map tool that uses a non hierarchical approach and I found nothing useful.

For example [XMind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMind) is even trying to sabotage my non hierarchical attempts. Every time I move two free floating nodes too close together it makes one child of the other. Very frustrating!

The most useful thing I found until now is [Bubbl.us](https://bubbl.us/), but it doesn't look nice and doesn't really help with layout or anything. I might as well draw one by hand.

Must have:

- non sabotaging environment to non hierarchical mind maps

Preferably:

- free (but if it's really good looking and does what I want I would
  pay for it)
- auto arrangement (imagine I just want to write down 20 keywords, tell
  each one of them what other nodes it shares a connection with and *BAM*
  everything arranges itself in a nice cloud)

Comment: How about http://www.thebrain.com/ though it is a paid product. As a side note, [NON-HIERARCHICAL MIND MAPPING, INTUITIVE LEAPFROGGING, AND THE MATRIX: TOOLS FOR A THREE PHASE PROCESS OF PROBLEM SOLVING IN INDUSTRIAL DESIGN](https://www.designsociety.org/publication/19594/non-hierarchical_mind_mapping_intuitive_leapfrogging_and_the_matrix_tools_for_a_three_phase_process_of_problem_solving_in_industrial_design).

Comment: For which operating system?

Comment: For XMind: You can hold the ALT key down while dragging nodes or branches and it won't try to merge them with anything.

Comment: Isn't a no-hierarchical mindmap an oxymoron?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am having a little trouble grokking a non-hierarchical mind map, but I think you mean that not all nodes connect to others, and that their is not one central "mother node" (?)

Sounds like you could just use any diagramming app. My favourite is [yEd](https://www.yworks.com/products/yed). Check out [the gallery](https://www.yworks.com/products/yed/gallery) to see if you like what it produces.

Here's something I found on Google image search:

[image]

---

As an alternative to the drag & drop likes of Yed, [Dia](http://dia-installer.de/), etc, since you say

> auto arrangement (imagine I just want to write down 20 keywords, tell
>   each one of them what other nodes it shares a connection with and BAM
>   everything arranges itself in a nice cloud)

I am a great fan of diagramming apps which take a plain text input and produce a diagram. And the undisputed king, for  a few decades now, is [GraphViz](https://www.graphviz.org/). Again, take a look at [the gallery](https://www.graphviz.org/gallery/), to see if you can find one that you like.

Here's a simple example, but you can get very complex if you want to.

This input:

```
graph G {
  e
  subgraph clusterA {
    a -- b;
    subgraph clusterC {
      C -- D;
    }
  }
  subgraph clusterB {
    d -- f
  }
  d -- D
  e -- clusterB
  clusterC -- clusterB
}
```

generates this diagram:

[image]

Comment: GraphViz is the code my mind map dreams are made of.

Comment: Yup! I use it for ***lots*** of different things - a truly great tool

Answer (score 0):

The only one I know is Scapple, but it is not free (though not expensive) and there's no IOS or android version. I'm also looking for an alternative.

Comment: Couldn't you even provide a link? it would be better, though, to provide some text to explain how you think your answer helps with the OP's question.